# If $\int_\Omega |\nabla (u-M)^+|^2 = 0$ where $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, and $u|_{\partial\Omega} \leq M$, does it follow that $u \leq M$ a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be  a bounded domain.

If $\int_\Omega |\nabla (u-M)^+|^2 = 0$ where $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, and $u|_{\partial\Omega} \leq M$, does it follow that $u \leq M$ a.e?

I do not think this is true since we could have $u$ to be a constant bigger than $M$ except on hte boundary, which is null.

Comment: $\nabla (u-M) = 0 a.e $ then apply the maximum theorem .

Answer (score 3):

This is true, with an appropriate interpretation of "$u\le M$ on $\partial \Omega$". When working with Sobolev functions, you don't want to just define them on $\partial \Omega$ independently of what they do in $\Omega$; the resulting object would be an uninteresting combination of two unrelated functions.

Instead, the inequality on the boundary should be understood in the sense of *trace operator*. Without going into technicalities, having boundary values $\le M$ amounts to $(u-M)^+\in H_0^1(\Omega)$; you can take this as a definition of "$u\le M$ on $\partial \Omega$".

Then the conclusion is easy: a $H_0^1$ function with zero gradient must be identically zero. Indeed, it is constant a.e. (follows by mollification, or from the ACL property), and this constant must be $0$.